# Are ITS1 and ITS2 good for divergence time estimation?

Tags: molecular-evolution

I had a discussion with a colleague who told me internal transcribed spacers (ITSs) are not good for divergence time estimation:

- Because they are non protein coding genes;
- Because they belong to a gene family.

However, I was not able to find anything in the literature about that. Can someone please enlighten me?